# Is there a way to query a specific data point if it exists, otherwise query everything else?

Tags: sql, select, google-bigquery, where-clause

Say I have a table with a column called "Names" and with values "Mike", "John", "Kelly", and "Tina". Every day the values might change.

How would I structure the query so that if the table has the name "Tina", it only displays "Tina", but if it doesn't contain "Tina", it'll display everything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option to consider (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(flag) FROM (
  SELECT *, names = 'Tina' OR COUNTIF(names = 'Tina') OVER() = 0 AS flag
  FROM `project.dataset.table` 
)
WHERE flag
```

I would expected this version is significantly cheaper than another one with implicit join

Answer (score 1):

One option is `union all` ad `not exists`:

```
select name from mytable where name = 'Tina'
union all
select t.name from mytable t where not exists (select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.name = 'Tina')
```